# Why does HDMI out on my Canon 5D Mark III work with my TV but not my Lilliput monitor or BlackMagic Design Shuttle 2?

Tags: canon, hdmi, blackmagic

Facts as I observe them:

- I can use a mini-HDMI to HDMI cord to mirror my Canon 5D Mark III on my consumer Samsung television
- I can use a consumer HDMI device such as an Apple TV to power my Lilliput monitor and capture over my BlackMagic Design Shuttle 2 -> UltraStudio Mini Recorder setup
- I cannot use my Canon 5D Mark III to run HDMI over the  Shuttle 2 -> Mini Recorder

The video is set to 1920x1080 with 30fps. I know the BlackMagic devices like `720p59.94` and  and `1080p59.94`.  I have up-to-date `1.3.3` Canon firmware and have default settings except for `HDMI output + LCD` setting which is set to `Mirroring`. I am set to `P` mode.

I've established a Computer<->Mini Recorder setup in multiple applications using the working input so I believe the issue to be between the camera and the devices receiving its HDMI out. The behavior of the camera seems to change when I plug its output into one of the non-working sources, apparently leaving movie mode. When connected to the monitor and I turn it off, the display returns from black.

My guess here is that the TV is capable of some wildly varying HDMI standards while my camera and/or BlackMagic gear is not. It may not be capable of handling whatever `1920x1080 30fps IPB` output ends up being.  [This seems relevant](https://forums.creativecow.net/thread/280/376):

> -Has nothing to do with HDCP compliance, not required, so that is good.
>
> -If you have a display that does not work at 1080 in the live view mode with the Canon 5D Mark II it is probably attributable to one of
>   two things: Native preferred timing not set to 1920x1080i in monitor's
>   EDID or that the display type is listed as RGB color and default color
>   space is listed as sRGB in the monitor's EDID.

Can anyone tell me what may be causing this apparently flippant behavior and for bonus karma suggest a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which Lilliput monitor do you have and what exactly is the output format of the 5d Mkiii?

Not all Lilliput screens can display progressive resolutions. Sometimes cameras provide "fake" interlaced on the monitor out (PsF) even if recording progressive to avoid that problem. It is a common problem with the BM Pocket Cinema Camera and (some) Lilliput screens since the BMPCC only outputs 24p/25p/30p.

Here is a list of hdmi modes the different Lilliput models support: [http://lilliputdirect.com/index.php?*route*=supported-hdmi-modes](http://lilliputdirect.com/index.php?_route_=supported-hdmi-modes)

There is no quick workaround to that problem since the hyperdeck shuttle does simple hdmi pass-through and no image conversion.

Answer (score 2):

Some DSLRs output HDMI video that does not meet full HDMI specifications. It is not unusual to find combinations of source and destination gear that is incompatible.  The HDMI can be viewed on permissive screens (consumer TV receivers, etc.) but not on more professional gear that strictly adheres to the HDMI standard protocols.

Comment: As far as I know, this has nothing to do with the HDMI specs. Progressive resolutions are definitely part of the hdmi specs. I think the reason why a lot of cheap monitors cannot display certain resolutions is because they use a certain, fairly cheap hdmi display driver by realtek which simply cannot handle progressive resolutions.